# Disable Alt + F4 for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I need to disable the close event using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> keyboard shortcut. For now, I'm trying to filter the events in my Scene for this keypress and consume it, but didn't have any success, the close event happens anyway. Follows bellow part of my code:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.isAltDown() && event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.F4)) {
        event.consume();
    }
});

primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((ev) -> System.exit(0));
```

Comment: Have you tried the same thing with `primaryStage.addEventFilter`?

Comment: Yes. Same behavior.

Comment: I don't know much about JavaFX, but I think you might be attacking this problem from the wrong angle. Perhaps you simply need to stop Java from exiting itself from any circumstances and then handle the cases where it should manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to disable the implicit exit:

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

and then create a button which will close the app on click:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Close");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
       System.exit(0);
    }
});
```