# JavaFx exit fullscreen when press cmd + q

Tags: macos, javafx, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

JavaFx exit fullscreen when press cmd + q in OSX. Even trapping onCloseRequest event is also not helping app not to exit full screen.
Anyone faced this issue? How to disable this behavior and allow app to be always fullscreen?

Any help is appreciated.

Below are my code what I am trying.

```
public class FullScreenScene extends Application {

/**
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("TilePane");

    // Adding StackPane
    StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    Text txt = new Text("This is a full screen JavaFX 2 Scene...");
    txt.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 72));
    txt.setFill(Color.RED);
    sp.getChildren().add(txt);

    // Adding StackPane to the Scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    // Set full screen
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(ev -> {
        ev.consume();
    });
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried calling  `.setResizable(false);` on primaryStage?

Comment: I do not know OSX but here is one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934330/4629012) which could help you. BTW I recommand using `Stage#setMaximized(true)` with the appropriate `StageStyle` instead of fullscreen especially if the application could be launched on two screens computers.

Comment: .setResizable(false) did work in Java 8 update 25, but not working in Java 8 update 144.

Comment: Seems to be an unresolved bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8117679